# Is every Switch capable of Network Access Server?

Tags: switch, radius, aaa, route-server

i am learning about Radius Server and particularly freeRadius. NAS devices are responsible for sending Authentication requests to the Radius Server. NAS devices include like Switch, wireless access points, DSLM. My question is Every Switch(different manufacturers) capable of NAS.

Comment: I've removed the request for product recommendations since that's off topic here.

Comment: Many switch vendors support radius authentication since it's an open standard, but I'm sure you'll find some brands and models which don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not all switches support it.

As you may have learned already this is part of the [IEEE 802.1x standard](http://www.ieee802.org/1/pages/802.1x-2004.html) , so the devices that support it are those who list `802.1X` as a supported feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think most of the devices in market support forwarding EAPOL message to free radius(Authentication server) but there are several switches which are not capable of handling EAP message. Hence it might not be able to authenticate supplicant through authentication server.